# In the Azure portal, What is Mode for an app service?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

When I view an App Service in the Azure portal and click on the properties "blade" I see a Mode property of Standard.
A different App Service has a Mode property of Shared.

What is Mode in an App Service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mode means the `pricing tier` of [Azure App Service plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-hosting-plans) which is used by the web app.

For example, `Standard` means that the `pricing tier` of service plan is Standard; `Shared` means that the `pricing tier` of service plan is Shared.

You can refer to [Azure App Service plan overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-hosting-plans) for more details.